# How to make UIWebView Blank when its already loaded once?

Tags: ios, ios5, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I am allocating and initializing the UIWebView in the viewDidLoad and I am loading the webview in the viewDidAppear.

So i want to clear the contents the UIWebView once its loaded by clicking a button.

Answer (score 1):

```
   [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];
```

Load the blank on button click.

Comment: @Gourav.J If your problem is solved then you should accept answer,Clicking on the right.